# How to detect which plugin performs an action on save in Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I'm editing the [postcss custom properties](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties) project, and if I add a comment to the top of `test/index.js` Atom adds commas to the file on save, such that I get the following errors when I run the test.

```
 /home/ole/postcss-custom-properties/test/index.js
 19:30  error  Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle
 90:22  error  Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle
 149:30  error  Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle
 192:19  error  Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle
 199:25  error  Missing trailing comma  comma-dangle

 ✖ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)
```

How do I figure which plugin is doing this?